# Why have my Chilli Pepper plants started to develop small slightly translucent spots/blotches on the leaves?

Tags: plant-care, diseases, leaves, peppers, chili

See the photos attached of the leaves.

I planted these chilli peppers about 2 months ago (march 2020) and they have been sat on my windowsill. We've had relatively hot and sunny weather for the UK this spring.

The seeds are planted in a general purpose compost in large pots.

I water when the soil looks dry and occasionally very sparingly include some tomato feed/general purpose house plant liquid fertilizer (baby bio) every 2-3 weeks.

The liquid tomato feed has an NPK ratio of 4:2:6 
The baby bio general purpose houseplant food has a ratio of 10:4:2.

The advice online is quite confusing and doesn't seem to exactly match the symptoms of my plants.

Is this a symptom of a nutrient deficiency, issues with water levels, or a virus/bacteria?

The symptoms are on every leaf of the three Chilli plants so I am reluctant to follow some advice I have seen on 'removing the effected area'.

[image: Chilli Leaf spots-Blotches]